# Search result page redirect ex.com/?s=searchterms to ex.com/searchterms

Tags: customization, search, redirect

I want to redirect search result page to a static page like
example.com/?s=searchterms to example.com/searchterms
or
example.com/?s=searchterms to example.com/searchterms.html

Any possibility in wordpress
I am able to redirect 
example.com/?s=searchterms to example.com/search/searchterms

Answer (score 1):

Write this in your theme's functions.php. 
Hope this helps you out.

```
function code_search() {
    if ( is_search() &&
         strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin/') === false &&
         strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/search/') === false ) {
         wp_redirect( get_bloginfo('home') . '/search/' . str_replace(' ', '_', str_replace('%20', '_', get_query_var('s'))));
         exit();
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'code_search');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but it redirect to http://example.com/search/searchterms                                                                                                  But i want search result page url like this                                                     http://example.com/searchterms   or http://example.com/mycustom/searchterms          Any hope?

Comment: @David777 For  example.com/mycustom/searchterms , replace "/search/" in if condition and also from wp_redirect, to "/mycustom/"